# Android, sending Leaderboards score after Turnbased match is finished

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I need to send the score of **both** players when the match is over because I need to know who is the winner to calc the score.

In this scenario only the player that take the last turn knows it. 
He can submit his score, but he can't submit his opponent score. So, how can i submit the score of the opponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit scores for other players. You can write out the scores in the game state and when the game is over and you call finishGame(), the loser will get a notification with the game state and a status of  MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETE.  Then you can submit the score for the local user.

Comment: yes but if the game is closed i cannot register listener right?

Comment: The last message with the status match_status_complete ends the lifecycle of the game - so you can show the "winning move" when ending the game.

Comment: So I have to open the app, query for completed match and push the score?

Comment: yes, but there is a notification which contains the info for the match.  It does require the player to do something (which i think is your point why this is less than a perfect solution).  alternatively, depending on your game logic, submit the score on each turn?

Comment: Ok, i will try but i don't find where i can access notification data. The documentation about turnbased is quite unclear. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

Just revisiting because I have recently implemented this feature for one of my quiz applications.

No multiplayer frameworks allow us to post the opponent's scores. The best way to update is to follow the steps below.

1. We need to locally store `mywinsCount` and `matchID` for which wins count is updated to avoid multiple updates in future.
2. Load all completed matches.
3. Iterate and check for match turn status `MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE`.
4. Check if the `matchID` is already used to update your leaderboard; if yes, ignore and go to the next.
5. Decide the winner based on your match data and update the leaderboard.
6. Use `matchID` and mark it as updated locally and ignore this match in future updates.

If the local player wins, update the leaderboard immediately.